# Remember user input from other website

Tags: language-agnostic

A registration webpage impressed me by knowing all my name, address, email, telephone number.
This is the first time i visit this website.
I guess that it might remember from other website with same id or name such as id="firstname"
id ="telephone" but i don't know exactly what is going on. How to implement this ?

---

Edit - Add more information.

I have done nothing, value is just appeared as page load.
This is what i got from view source.

```
    <div class="ui-form-field" id="ohfirstNameField">           
            <input class="ui-form-field-text ui-corner-all" name="ohfirstName" maxlength="4000" type="text" id="ohfirstName" required="required" value="Sarawut" />         
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not your browser that autocompleted these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen that before as well, and here is my theory. I believe the browser is storing basic information for you. A separate website cannot read any cookies not generated by itself (that would be a huge security issue), so that can't be it.

I think it is just a few fields that the browser stores. How to get at them, I am not sure. Is this Google Chrome you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You could use OpenId to get a similar effect. The user will be asked, if he allows the authenticating site to his data, but if admits it, you will be able to prefill your form with data from the user.